# The output displays zero instead of 23 (correct output) from nowhere

Tags: java, output

My codes are used to calculate CPF and now I'm working on getting the person's age since CPF calculation is based on age level. Since for CPF, for the people who is less than 35 years old, their CPF equivalent to '12*(0.16 + 0.20) * salary', and I assume people start working at 22 years old since they could only use CPF when they start working. Since the person's current monthly salary is $2000, and he only got $10,000 savings(include CPF), so after calculation, I think he only started working for one year and some more.
  Thus my coding should display the age of 23 but insted it shows 0 regardless of how I modified the codes, I have no idea which part of them is wrong and hope someone could help me figure them out. Thank you.

And here's my partial codes for output and input:

```
    public class mainclass {
// The mainclass is an executable class. You should run your program here.
public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* cpfCalculator takes in the following
     * (String name, double savings, double desiredAmt, double salary, String citizen)
     */

    cpfCalculator c = new cpfCalculator("El Salvador", 10000, 70000, 2000, "P", 0.451651);
    System.out.println("INPUT VALUES");
    System.out.println("*************");
    System.out.println("Person's Name:" + c.getName() + "_ Savings ($):" + c.getSavings() + "_ Desired Amount ($):" + c.getDesiredAmt());
    System.out.println("Salary ($):" + c.getSalary() + "_ Citizen or PR:" + c.getCitizen());
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("OUTPUT VALUES");
    System.out.println("*************");
    System.out.println(age.getAge());
    System.out.println("Employee CPF ($): " + c.getYcpf());
    System.out.println("Employer CPF ($): " + c.getBcpf());
    System.out.println("Total CPF per year ($): " + c.getTotalCpf());
    System.out.println("No of Years needed to achieve desired amount: " + c.getYearsToAchieve());
    System.out.println("Hi, " +c.getName() + ", you should " + c.getAdvice());
    System.out.println("The CPF accumulation schedule as follows : ");
    System.out.println("Yr. | CPF/yr ($) | Total Amt ($)");
    for (int j = 0; j<=c.getCpfAdviceArray().size()-1; j++){
        cpfAdvice wa = c.getCpfAdviceArray().get(j);
        System.out.println(wa.getYear() + " | " + wa.getCpf() + " | " +   (j+1)*wa.getTcpf());
    }
```

These are the ones used to calculate the age:

```
public class age {
private static int age;
private double salary;
private double savings;

    public age() {
        double a = 12*(0.16 + 0.20) * salary;
        double b = 2*a;
         if (a < savings)
             // only worked for less than one year
             age = 22;
         else if(a >= savings && b > salary )
             // age>22&&age<=35
             age = 23;
         else
             System.out.println("The person hasn't started working.");
}
    public age(double salary, double savings) {
        super();
        this.salary = salary;
        this.savings = savings;
    }
    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    public void setSavings(double savings) {
        this.savings = savings;
    }
    public double getSavings() {
        return savings;
    }
    public static int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post more code so we can help.  We should be able to see instantiation of age object...

Comment: Do you call `setSalary` and `setSavings`?

Comment: Since you are getting 0, this implies you are not setting the class instance variables (as suggested upthread), as they are initialized by the VM to 0 on instantiation.

Comment: I put setSalary and setSavings already but still not working :(

Comment: Now i get error message`Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getAge() from the type age` for `System.out.println(age.getAge());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you didn't understand how it works. 
Actually where is your `Age age = new Age();` ? 
this will call your `public age()` but at that time `salary`or `savings` aren't set to any value because you never set them or create another constructor with those params.

and finally you ask for the value by `getAge()` which won't calculate it again but just get you the bad calculated value.

So create a constructor with 2 params : `salary` and `saving` and then add your code from the other constructor this will change your output normally ;)

Actually It would be better in my opinion to create a method to calculate the age and not to put it in the constructor.

----- update -----

Change your age class to Age (and rename the file to Age.java)

```
public class Age 
{
    private int age = -1;
    private double salary;
    private double savings;

public Age() {
}
public Age(double salary, double savings) {
    super();
    this.salary = salary;
    this.savings = savings;
}
public double getSalary() {
    return salary;
}
public void setSalary(double salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}
public void setSavings(double savings) {
    this.savings = savings;
}
public double getSavings() {
    return savings;
}
public int getAge() {
    computeAge();
    return age;
}

public void computeAge()
{
    double a = 12*(0.16 + 0.20) * salary;
    double b = 2*a;
    if (a < savings)
        // only worked for less than one year
        age = 22;
    else if(a >= savings && b > salary )
        // age>22&&age<=35
        age = 23;
    else
        System.out.println("The person hasn't started working.");
}
```

}

But Age is a very strange name for a class because it's not really what it is...

then to call it :

```
cpfCalculator c = new cpfCalculator("El Salvador", 10000, 70000, 2000, "P", 0.451651);
System.out.println("INPUT VALUES");
System.out.println("*************");
System.out.println("Person's Name:" + c.getName() + "_ Savings ($):" + c.getSavings() + "_ Desired Amount ($):" + c.getDesiredAmt());
System.out.println("Salary ($):" + c.getSalary() + "_ Citizen or PR:" + c.getCitizen());
System.out.println("");

Age a = new Age( c.getSalary(), c.getSavings()); // ADD this line

System.out.println("OUTPUT VALUES");
System.out.println("*************");
System.out.println(age.getAge());
```

Comment: So do I also need to add `Age age = new Age()` ?

Comment: And if I used a method, the method type would be static, since `salary` and `saving` are inside the method, I have to also set them to be static, thus I could no longer have setter for them.

Answer (score 1):

You have no `else`, so your `age` is actually never set:

```
if (a < savings)
  // only worked for less than one year
  age = 22;
else if(a >= savings && b > salary )
  // age>22&&age<=35
  age = 23;
else
  age = DEFAULT_AGE;
```

Just define `DEFAULT_AGE`.

This happens because at the time your constructor is called, `salary` is `0.0d`. multiplication of `0` by anything is always `0`. Finally, you check that `a (=0.0D) < savings (=0.0D)`  which is `false` and `b (=0.0D) > salary (=0.0D)` is `false` as well.

Therefore `age` is never set.

Comment: Is there anything else I should set? Cause it's still not working :(

Comment: and i thought the amount of salary should depend on my input?